# Customizing block styles regarding some info | React

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing some pokedex stuff (like pokemon wikipedia). The idea is every pokemon has at least one type (or category). I want to customize these blocks (with type names) regarding **typesAndColors** object so that **grass** block will be green, **fire** block will be red, etc.

```
    const typesAndColors = {
        "normal": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#A3CB38",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "fighting":
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#3B3B98",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "flying":
        {  
            backgroundColor:  "#9AECDB",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "poison": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#a29bfe",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "ground": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#4b4b4b",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "rock": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#ccae62",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "bug": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#badc58",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "ghost": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#dfe6e9",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "steel": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#95afc0",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "fire": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#ff3838",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "water": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#3498db",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "grass": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#2ecc71",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "electric": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#fdcb6e",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "psychic": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#BDC581",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "ice": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#c7ecee",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "dragon": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#30336b",
            color: "#fff"
        },
        "dark": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#2C3A47",
            color: "#fff"
        },
        "fairy": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#e056fd",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "unknown": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            color: "#000"
        },
        "shadow": 
        {  
            backgroundColor: "#636e72",
            color: "#000"
        }
    };
...
    let items = [],
        itemSet = [];
    const styles = {
                backgroundColor: "",
                color: ""
            };
// arr consists of types (this info is fetched from url)
// example:
// [ [ grass, poison ], [ fire ], [ water ] ]

    arr.forEach(element => {
            element.forEach(el => {
                styles.backgroundColor = typesAndColors[el].backgroundColor;
                styles.color = typesAndColors[el].color;

                itemSet.push(
                    <div className="container__block" style={ styles }>
                        {el}
                    </div>
                );
            })

            items.push(itemSet);
            itemSet = [];
        })
...
// in the end, I paste { items } on a web-page
```

The problem is all the blocks are of the same color (look at screenshot below)
[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a new `styles` object for each. Otherwise they all get shared when it's time to render.